# Troubleshooting Communication Issue between Jetson Nano (Linux) and RS485-USB Converter in linux

Tags: linux, serial-port

I'm encountering a communication problem between my Jetson Nano (running Linux) and an RS485-USB converter. I'm seeking assistance in resolving this issue. Below are the details:

[image: converter][image: sensor]
I'm using the QinHeng Electronics CH340 serial converter along with the ZE03 sensor, which has an RX/TX cable. I have verified that the sensor is functioning correctly. My development environment consists of Jupyter Notebook and Python 3.10.

The problem I'm facing is that despite having the USB connection established on Linux and the port opened, communication is not occurring.

Here is the code I have used:

```py
import serial
import time

SERIAL_PORT = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
BAUD_RATE = 9600

# Initialize the serial port
ser = serial.Serial(SERIAL_PORT, BAUD_RATE, timeout=1)

# Set sensor mode as Q&A
ser.write(b'\xFF\x01\x78\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x83')  # Command to request gas data
time.sleep(0.1)
response1 = ser.read(9)  # Read response data
print(response1)

ser.write(b'\xFF\x01\x86\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x79')  # Command to request gas data
time.sleep(0.1)
response2 = ser.read(9)  # Read response data
print(response2)

ser.close()
```

The output I receive is as follows:

```
b' '
b' '
```

I'm not getting any response. Additionally, I have tried connecting the sensor using the UART 8 and 10 pins on the Jetson Nano but encountered the same issue.

To further debug, I modified the serial port configuration and tried again:

```py
SERIAL_PORT = '/dev/ttyTHS1' # Just changed the port
BAUD_RATE = 9600

# Initialize the serial port
ser = serial.Serial(SERIAL_PORT, BAUD_RATE, timeout=1)

# Set sensor mode as Q&A
ser.write(b'\xFF\x01\x78\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x83')  # Command to request gas data
time.sleep(0.1)
response1 = ser.read(9)  # Read response data
print(response1)

ser.write(b'\xFF\x01\x86\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x79')  # Command to request gas data
time.sleep(0.1)
response2 = ser.read(9)  # Read response data
print(response2)

ser.close()
```

The output I receive is as follows:

```
b'\xffx\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x87'
b'\xff\x86\x00\x0b\x02\x00\x00\x00m'
```

I have downloaded the driver file from the internet and ensured that it is correctly installed. I don't believe this issue is related to permission problems since I have added the driver file in the `rules.d` folder.

To verify if there are any driver-related issues, I executed the following command:

```
dmesg | grep ch341
```

Based on the output, it seems that the driver is not the cause of the problem since the Jetson Nano detects the USB.

When I write terminal

```
ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
```

The output is

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 188, 0  7월  6 10:22 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Any assistance in resolving this communication issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Because all USB devices include some standard identification properties, `lsusb` can show any (non-broken) USB device even if there is no driver available for it. Please run `ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0` and **edit your question** to show the output.